# Recalling functions inside the same function to try and catch failure in a loop

Tags: lua

When I run this code on my phone, It runs through every step and then when it finds a fault it will revert backwards to the beginning of the code then alarms out. What I want it to do is run each function exactly the way its been doing, but, only to Alert me when the last function is run. Log print at the end of the code.

```
--Step 1 Open Quests
questopen = function()
  log("Opening Quests")
local step1 = getColor(64, 803)
  log("Fetched Quest Icon")
  if step1 == 9127481 then
    tap(64, 803)
    log("Matched Quest Icon")
    else
    log("Failed Quest Icon")
    alert("Out of Sync - Check Logs for failure")
    collectgarbage()
    end
  end

--Step 2 Accept Quest
questaccept = function()
  log("Accepting Quest")
  local step2 = getColor(426, 1004)
  log("Fetched Accept Quest")
  if step2 == 2300441 then
    tap(426, 1004)
    log("Matched Accept Quest")
    else
    log("Failed Accept Quest")
    collectgarbage()
    questopen()
    end
  end

--Step 3 Skip Dialogue
skip = function()
  log("Skipping Dialogue")
  local step3 = getColor(564, 1083)
  log("Fetched Skip Dialogue")
  if step3 == 2300441 then
    tap(564, 1083)
    log("Matched Skip Dialogue")
    else
    log("Failed Skip Dialogue")
    collectgarbage()
    questaccept()
    end
  end

--Step 4 Quest Confirm
confirm = function()
  log("Confirming Quest")
  local step4 = getColor(124, 578)
  log("Fetched Confirm Quest")
  if step4 == 15921906 then
    tap(124, 578)
    log("Matched Confrim Quest")
    else
    log("Failed Confirm Quest")  
    collectgarbage()
    skip()
    end
  end

--Step 5 Quest Go
go = function()
  log("Quest Go")
  local step5 = getColor(424, 990)
  log("Fetched Quest Go")
  if step5 == 13750737 then
    tap(424, 990)
    log("Matched Quest Go")
    else
    log("Failed Quest Go")
    collectgarbage()
    confirm()
    end
  end 

questopen()
usleep(3000000)
questaccept()
usleep(3000000)
skip()
usleep(3000000)
confirm()
usleep(3000000)
go()
usleep(3000000)
```

I have specifically designed this to test the detection methods, So I expect it to fail at `Step 2 Accept Quests`. But currently I want to work a better method of error detection, I want the alert. But it alerts each and every failure.

I want the code to work backwards at the first failure, but I don't want it to keep moving forward at the same time, which the error reports will show.

[Gyazo image of error log](https://gyazo.com/fb448fb84e8bb43f03b217c9c70e0d3b)

Comment: I'm getting the impression that your problem may be due to the way you made your functions call each other and not because of a phose-specific issue. Do you think you can make a standalone  version of your problem in plain Lua so we can more easily run it?

Comment: Btw, Lua means "Moon" in Portuguese, so only the first letter should be capitalized :)